# What are my options for interpolation of such data

Tags: math, interpolation, bezier, approximation

Having dramatically different step sizes, and not much data. We have data like `>--4-6----3-9----4-7----9-3----4-1---->` ( `-` is step here ) and in real life this data is looped in a circle. What polynomials/formulas can help me with interpolation of such data? Will Bezier work?

Comment: Fitting a smooth curve to discrete data is often misleading.

Comment: When you say "looped in a circle" do you mean the data is periodic?  Do you know the period?

Comment: Does the interpolated curve have to pass through the control (i.e., given data) points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fit Cublic Splines on each set. A single BeZier curve is not accurate enough (unless you know otherwise). Another option is [Chebyschev](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) Polynomials.

Comment: IIRC, Beziers don't pass through the control points, so I am not sure it will fit the OP's requirement. OTOH, the OP did not really mention if this IS a requirement.